# How to remove whitespace when collapsing cards

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am writing a filter search to filter through cards of customer data. The search functions work, but when the cards collapse they leave degrees of whitespace which increases as you select the cards closer to the bottom.

Here is what the page looks like uncollapsed:

[image: Here is what the page looks like uncollapsed]

And this is what it looks like collapsed:

[image: And this is what it looks like collapsed]

This is my HTML container for the area:

```
<div class="container pt-3 pb-3">
    <div class="form-outline" id="customer-search-bar">
        <input type="search" id="filter" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" >
    </div>
    <div class="card-lists" id="card-lists">
       <div class="row">
          {% for data in raw.CustomerDataEntries %}
          <div class="card col-sm-12 mb-3" id="card-perim">
             <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Customer ID: {{ data.ExternalId }}</h5>
                <h5 class="card-title">Forename: {{ data.Fields.forename }}</h5>
                <h5 class="card-title">Surname: {{ data.Fields.surname }}</h5>
                <h5 class="card-title">Postcode: {{ data.Fields.post_code }}</h5>
                <h5 class="card-title">Matches: {{ data.Matches }}</h5>
                <a href="{%  url 'portal:customers_details'  data.ExternalId %}" class="tableButton">Details</a>
                <a href="{%  url 'portal:customers_edit' data.ExternalId %}"  class="tableButton">Edit</a>
             </div>
          </div>
          {% endfor %}
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my CSS style sheet for the section:

```
#card-perim{
    border: hidden;
}

#card-body{
    padding: 2em;
}

#customer-search-bar{
    margin: 1em;
}
```

And this is my JavaScript code for the filter search:

```
let filter = document.querySelector('#filter');
filter.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
  searchID();
});

function searchID() {
  const input = filter.value.toUpperCase();
  const cardContainer = document.querySelector('#card-lists');
  const cards = cardContainer.querySelectorAll('.card-body');

  cards.forEach(card => {
    card.style.display = 'none';
    card.querySelectorAll(".card-body h5.card-title").forEach(title => {
      if (title.innerText.toUpperCase().indexOf(input) > -1) {
        card.style.display = "block";
      }
    });
  });
}
```

How can I fix it?

I have tried a few different things, but I don't know whether it's the CSS or JavaScript that is causing this problem.

Comment: select by card not card-body, your hiding card-body, col-sm-12 has padding and mb-3 obviously contributes whitespace

Comment: additionally, there should only be one id="" per document, the id="card-perim" in the loop should be removed or changed to a class

Comment: In any case, you should verify the output HTML via the browser dev tools, see if there are elements created, which ones and what CSS applies. That's what dev tools are for.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I have tried selecting the card and switching the display to none but it doesn't take effect like how it does with the card-body